# How to Disable Git Credentials Manager on Windows (Visual Studio 2017)

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio, credential-manager

I got a question regarding Visual Studio 2017 and Git on Windows 7. In our environment, not every user has an individual Windows account as these machines are shared. Sadly, there is no way to change that fact. We are using Bitbucket for managing Git repositories. In this system, every user has its own login.

Because of this, it is very important for us to **not** save the credentials for each user within the system. Furthermore, we would like to easily switch between the different authors on every commit. The reason for this problem is the fact that the credentials and the actual author of a commit are not connected to each other. But this is a relatively minor issue.

What is more critical is the fact that Visual Studio is storing the credentials of each user to Windows' built-in Credential Manager as a "Generic Credential". This means even after a reboot of the system, the login is saved in Windows and Visual Studio does not ask for them anymore. This is a very critical issue to us. We have tried the following approaches on different systems to eliminate the chance of a local error:

- Disable storing passwords in the Credential Manager using the Group Policy Editor: Did not work, because this does not disable storing generic passwords.
- Remove the Git Credential Manager from all config files: Did not work in Visual Studio. When using any other Git client, this solves the problem.
- Remove the Git Credential Manager executable from the program folder: Did not have any effect
- Edit the Registry Key "disabledomaincreds" in the Registry: Did not have any effect
- Disable the Credential Manager Service in services.msg: The application could not be started anymore, but Visual Studio still saved the credentials in it

I would appreciate any help regarding this topic. Thanks in advance!